# I am having some problems here-Date Picker and all javascript including client validation not working in a Dynamically loaded Partial View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am working with ASP.NET MVC 3 (Razor)
I loaded a partial view by holds a form by clicking on Ajax Link that is located on my view as follows

@Ajax.ActionLink("Students List", "Create", "Student", new AjaxOptions {OnSuccess = "updatePlaceholder", UpdateTargetId = "holder" })

The partial view loads properly, but I discovered that the Telerek DatePicker isn't showing when I click on the button to bring it down
and also client side validations arent working also. I followed the approch described here but it still insn't working
http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/using-with-partial-views-loaded-via-ajax.html
 My code is below

HERE IS MY VIEW

@Ajax.ActionLink("Students List", "Create", "Student", new AjaxOptions {OnSuccess = "updatePlaceholder", UpdateTargetId = "holder" })

function updatePlaceholder(context) {
        // the HTML output of the partial view
        var html = context.get_data();

        // the DOM element representing the placeholder
        var placeholder = context.get_updateTarget();

        // use jQuery to update the placeholder. It will execute any JavaScript statements
        $(placeholder).html(html);

        // return false to prevent the automatic update of the placeholder
        return false;
    }

HERE IS MY PARTIALVIEW

@model MyUniversity.Models.Student

@using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions {UpdateTargetId="holder"}))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    
        Student
  @Html.Telerik().DateTimePicker().Name("EnrollmentDate").Value(DateTime.Now.ToString())
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EnrollmentDate)

```
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

}

@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")

Here is my _Layout.cshtml with the registered scripts

@ViewBag.Title

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.debug.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.debug.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
@(Html.Telerik().StyleSheetRegistrar().DefaultGroup(group => group.Add("telerik.common.css").Add("telerik.telerik.css").Combined(true).Compress(true)))
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

@(Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar().Globalization(true).DefaultGroup(group => group.Combined(true).Compress(true)))

Answer (score 0):

I have partial view that is loaded without Ajax. I had trouble making both the validation and Telerik datepicker popup to work. On my partial view I added the three scripts for validation:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But with this the popup wouldnt work, so I added these scripts to my `_layout.cshtml` just before:

`@Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar()`

I had already registered the following scripts on the `_layout.cshtml` page on the top:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftAjaxTemplates.debug.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/ui/jquery.ui.core.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.ui.tabs.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- Telerik Extensions for MVC Scripts -->
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/2011.2.712/telerik.combobox.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/2011.2.712/telerik.grid.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/2011.2.712/telerik.grid.editing.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/2011.2.712/telerik.grid.filtering.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/2011.2.712/telerik.grid.grouping.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/2011.2.712/telerik.grid.reordering.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/2011.2.712/telerik.grid.resizing.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/2011.2.712/telerik.datetimepicker.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/2011.2.712/telerik.datepicker.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.2.6.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

After that all seems to work fine.